# Firebase cloud functions not being triggered

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up cloud functions in firebase, and couldn't get it to run for when a user is followed, so tried setting up a simple project for creating a user, and am now trying for any change on the users branch of the database and it is still never triggered. The function shows up in my dashboard, but never triggers.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onUserCreateNotification = functions.database.ref('/users/')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      //const userUid = context.params.followedUid;
      console.log('We have a new user UID:');
  
    });
```

Comment: yep users node is lowercase, I guess the database.ref part at the beginning is somehow wrong, but it is uplaoding the functions to the correct project

Comment: Just tried reinitializing another folder from scratch and uploading again and still nothing in the logs/invocations

Comment: It runs on the test console if I put this and hit test: {"users": "lsdjfksfjskdflajfkdsjkl"}, but not if I create a user outside of the test console, even just hitting add document in the database doesn't trigger it

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: unfortunately, don't think I ever figured out the issue @denislexic

Answer (score 0):

Try: `exports.onUserCreateNotification = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')`

Comment: tried that before and just tried again and it still says 0 invocations and nothing in the logs either